# Clojure REPL in Windows

Tags: windows, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to learn Clojure, but rather than opening up a full-on IDE each time I'd like to be able to have a batch file (or similar) that opens up a decent REPL for quickly hacking examples. (i.e. I'm not looking for an Emacs/Netbeans/Eclipse IDE discussion).

For instance, this starts up the most basic REPL:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\clojure-1.2.0\
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
```

and if you add the jline and clojure-contrib jar files to the clojure directory then

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\clojure-1.2.0\
java -cp .;jline-0_9_5.jar;clojure.jar;clojure.contrib.jar jline.ConsoleRunner clojure.main
```

Comment: (May have answered my own question!!)

Comment: When you get your solution working, post it right here as an answer- will be useful.

Comment: Going forward... the best bet is http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/06/24/its-playtime/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a stand alone repl with decent classpath management take a look at cljr:

https://github.com/liebke/cljr

This provides a cljr.bat script that works very nicely under windows and provides convenient management of what is on the classpath and the ability to downloand/install clojure packages.

Comment: Managed to get this working, but doesn't seem the most clear guide for installation.  Will have to have a closer look, in case I have missed anything!

Comment: The path conventions listed in the cljr documentation are unix based but otherwise it works. Steps 1 and 2 are straight forward. Step 3 for windows should read something like add "%USERPROFILE%/.cljr/bin" to your path. Typing cljr at the command line in windows then runs the cljr.bat script.

Comment: I've been using the swingrepl a bit when I don't want to open an IDE...and that's been very useful...so for now, this is my suggested answer.  I have also used leiningen a little, but for the basics this hasn't been quite what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).  From there, download the windows zip, put the `lein` directory in your PATH and run:

```
lein repl
```

Enjoy!

Comment: lein seems to have won in the endurance race, cljr's master branch has 0 commits in the last 3 years.

Comment: Lein uses its own copy of Clojure which is often a version or two behind the latest Clojure.